# How much math must you know, to sink another submarine while both were submerged in 1945?

Tags: math-history

I'm just curious how much math [Lt J S Launders DSC RN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jimmy_Launders)

> Launders was a "rising star" in the [Royal Navy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_Navy) submarine command at the time.[[2]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jimmy_Launders#cite_note-U864-2) a "boy-wonder with a genius for mathematics,"[[2]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jimmy_Launders#cite_note-U864-2) which gave him a tremendous edge in making the necessary vector calculations (manual or minimally mechanical-computer assisted reckoning of speed and trajectories for targets, torpedoes, attacking vessels and currents) that were part of submarine warfare tactics of the day.[[2]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jimmy_Launders#cite_note-U864-2)

must've known when submerged in his 
[HMS Venturer (P68)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMS_Venturer_(P68)),  he torpedoed *U-864*.

> *Venturer* had only eight torpedoes as opposed to the 22 carried by *U-864*. After three hours Launders decided to make a prediction of *U-864*'s zig-zag, and released a spread of his torpedoes into its predicted course. This manual computation of a firing solution against a three-dimensionally manoeuvring target was the first occasion on which techniques were used and became the basis of modern computer-based torpedo targeting systems. Prior to this attack, no target had been sunk by torpedo where the firing ship had to consider the target's position in three-dimensional terms, where the depth of the target was variable and not a fixed value. The computation thus differs fundamentally from those performed by analogue torpedo fire-control computers which regarded the target in strictly 2D terms with a constant depth determined by the target's draught.

Comment: Interesting question. You may want to repost at http://hsm.stackexchange.com